# How to silence the output from this R package?

Tags: r

I'm playing a bit with the `LowRankQP()` package in R, and even setting `verbose=FALSE` still produces a lot of outputs (see example below).

The outputs are coming from the compiled part of the code. Is there a way (a wrapping function?) in R to make a call to `LowRankQP()` absolutely silent (i.e. not print anything on the **screen**) without modifying the underlying compiled code (neither of the email addresses associated with this package is still active)?

```
library(LowRankQP)

Vmat <- matrix(0,6,6)
diag(Vmat) <- c(1, 1,1,0,0,0)
dvec <- c(0,-5,0,0,0,0)
Amat <- matrix(c(-4,-3,0,-1,0,0,2,1,0,0,-1,0,0,-2,1,0,0,-1),6,3)
bvec <- c(-8,2,0)
uvec <- c(100,100,100,100,100,100)

aa<-LowRankQP(Vmat,dvec,t(Amat),bvec,uvec,method="CHOL")

# LowRankQP CONVERGED IN 15 ITERATIONS
# 
#     Primal Feasibility    =   2.5719308e-16
#     Dual Feasibility      =   7.1949984e-16
#     Complementarity Value =   3.3066705e-11
#     Duality Gap           =   3.3065273e-11
#     Termination Condition =   9.7802929e-12
```

It's the part that starts with "LowRankQP CONVERGED IN 15 ITERATIONS" that i want away with..

Ubuntu 11.04, R version 2.12.1 and LowRankQP() 1.0.1.

Comment: Please add a reproducible example. I have no issues with it from the few tests I did.

Comment: Not reproducible on Windows, I get no output whatsoever. Please 1) update to the latest version, and 2) if this persists, notify the developers of the package. This smells like some bug/inconsistency between linux and Windows versions.

Comment: Thanks J.M. (i already run R/the package's latest version so i'll mail the devel).

Comment: Apparently the package is no longer actively maintained (the address behind the maintainer is dead).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sink(file=NULL) does NOT work, since it **closes** the last sink, nothing more.

> > sink(file=NULL) Warning message: In sink(file = NULL) : no sink to remove

What does work though is:

```
f = file()
sink(file=f) ## silence upcoming output using anonymous file connection
... your code here ...
sink() ## undo silencing
close(f)
```

Using an anonymous file has the advantage of being platform-agnostic, i.e. you don't have to come up with a temporary file name.

Example:

```
f = file()
sink(file=f)
example(glm)
sink()
close(f)
```

I've used sink() successfully for other functions (e.g. normalmixEM2comp {mixtools}).

(edit: the first version of this post did not use an explicit file handle, and thus gave a warning -- or even an error if you call the above snippet often enough). This is now fixed by using close(f).

Answer (score 2):

Are you familiar with the R function `sink()`? From its help page:

```
sink                   package:base                    R Documentation

Send R Output to a File

Description:

     ‘sink’ diverts R output to a connection.

     ‘sink.number()’ reports how many diversions are in use.

     ‘sink.number(type = "message")’ reports the number of the
     connection currently being used for error messages.

Usage:

     sink(file = NULL, append = FALSE, type = c("output", "message"),
          split = FALSE)

     sink.number(type = c("output", "message"))

Arguments:

    file: a writable connection or a character string naming the file
          to write to, or ‘NULL’ to stop sink-ing.
```

The `file=NULL` argument is what you may want here.

Comment: thanks D.E. Would you know of any way to avoid these print outs splashing the terminal window as well -it is very annoying ?

Comment: `sink(file=NULL)` does that: **all** output goes to NULL.

Comment: Thanks D.E.: then i have not been able to use it: Where in the code above should i had sink(file=NULL) so that the message does not print in the screen?

Comment: Before you invoke the commands that generate the output you aim ti suppress.  Did you *read the help page* for `sink()` ?

Comment: Also kinda ironic that you insist on calling everybody by their initials when a) nobody signs with their initials here and b) you yourself hide behind an anonymous handle.

Comment: Dirk Eddelbuettel (?):> what you suggest works for scripts (as in capture.output(print("yahoo")) for example). But i couldn't get it to work on the function above (i think this is because the output are printed from the compiled code).

Answer (score 2):

Based on cbielow's answer, here's a small function that silences `cat()` and `print()` (but not `message()` or `warning()`) and returns whatever the expression returned:

```
shut_up = function(expr) {
  #temp file
  f = file()

  #write output to that file
  sink(file = f)

  #evaluate expr in original environment
  y = eval(expr, envir = parent.frame())

  #close sink
  sink()

  #get rid of file
  close(f)

  y
}
```

Tests:

```
> shut_up(print(1))
[1] 1
> shut_up(cat(1))
NULL
> shut_up(message(1))
1
NULL
> shut_up(warning(1))
[1] "1"
Warning message:
In eval(expr, envir = parent.frame()) : 1
```

Note that output is returned for `print()` and `warning()` because these functions silently return their input, while `cat()` and `message()` return `NULL`.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i could do it by commenting out lines 413->418  of LowRankQP.c and reinstalling it, from the .tar.gz (or alternatively adding an new option verbose==2).

Answer (score 0):

I don't if it would work, but you can try `invisible()`. I don't know the function you are ussing and I don't know if invisible can silence `cat()`. But you could give a go.

Comment: All invisible really does, is prevent the return value of its contents of being printed, so this shouldn't help.