# How to silence the output from system commands in R?

Tags: r

I want to silence the output of `covr::package_coverage(quiet = FALSE)`.  The output of this function is quite verbose: It calls `install.package()`, which prints a lot of text.

After browsing around, I have already tried:

- `invisible` (which does not work, and it shouldn't)
- `capture.output` does not remove everything
- `sink()` (as described in [How to silence the output from this R package?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177629/how-to-silence-the-output-from-this-r-package)) also does not work (which is not surprising, since `capture.output` is based on `sink()`).

In case it is of interest, I am running R 3.3 on Windows.

(Note: Funnily, the covr::package_coverage fails with `quiet = TRUE`, so this is not an option.)

Comment: Try `suppressMessages`. It might work depending on how the screen print expressions were generated in the package.

Comment: Thanks, but no, doesn't work.  I believe that `suppressMessages` only suppresses messages written out using `message(...)`.

Comment: Not sure if this is already available in R 3.3, but setting the "ignore.stdout" or "ignore.stderr" attributes (or both) to TRUE is one way that tends to works on Unix in later versions (see my answer in e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45143689/r-supress-console-output-of-a-system-or-shell-command/66003753#66003753).

Comment: @Phil Thanks. The linked question does not mention the `ignore.std...` answers, though. In any case, if you post your answer here as an answer, then I can try and accept it.

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62675472/how-to-turn-off-all-console-outputs-in-r