# R supress console output of a system or shell command

Tags: r, system-calls

I have this windows-batchfile which I'm calling from R using the `shell()` command. This batchfile does some calculations and writes them on the disk but also on the screen. I'm interested in the disk-output, only. I cannot change the batchfile.

The batchfile might be something silly like:

```
@echo off
echo 1 + 2
@echo 1 + 2 > C:\TEMP\batchoutput.txt 
exit
```

I tried

```
shell("batchfile.bat", invisible = TRUE)
```

> 1 + 2

```
shell("batchfile.bat", show.output.on.console = FALSE)
```

> Error in system(cmd, intern = intern, wait = wait | intern, show.output.on.console = wait,  : 
>     formal argument "show.output.on.console" matched by multiple actual arguments

```
system("batchfile.bat", invisible = T)
```

> 1 + 2

```
system("batchfile.bat", show.output.on.console = F)
```

> Warning message:
>   running command 'C:\TEMP\batchfile.bat' had status 1

Is there a way of supressing the console-output on R?

Comment: `system("batchfile.bat", wait = FALSE)` did the trick

Comment: It successfully supresses the output on screen. Unfortunately, the batch isn't executed correctly then. It does not write the file to disk.

Comment: `wait = FALSE` won't work with other scripts, @smoff correct

Comment: `invisible(shell(cmd = "batchfile.bat", intern = TRUE))` seems to work.

Comment: it also return a `Warning message` but you can suppress it with `options(warn=-1)`

Comment: Funny. I don't get a `Warning message`.

Answer (score -1):

```
options(warn = -1)
shell("You command")
options(warn = 0)
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally discouraged. Please provide more context about why this helps the OP address the problem.

Comment: It looks pretty self-explanatory to me.  Warn off, shell command, warn on.  I understand it's discouraged and would agree.  But some answers don't need further comment when the code itself explains it.