# How to turn off all console outputs in R

Tags: r

Is there a function that turns off **all** possible console outputs so that R does not write anything into the console, no matter the source of the message?

*Background*:
Some functions in R do automatically write messages, warnings and other into the console which can easily be supressed. But R also sometimes writes text into the console, that can not be turned of by all generel commands like **supressMessages**, **supressWarnings**, **invisible()** etc. Even the **catch** function and others like **trycatch**, **options()** can not capture these messages. These Messages can sometimes be overwhelming because they spam massivly into the console, eg. 30 Messages per function call for 10000+ function calls. What i am looking for is a command that can be written into the R script that prevent that there are written messages, even when they came from 3rd party tools called within R. And is there also a command to turn on console writing again?

Comment: Are you looking for something like `sink`?

Comment: Hi Dason, no, have tried sink already, just forget to metion it above. I guess my problem is much deeper within a specific r function cause none of all the methods suppresses their warning message.

Comment: Were you just using a single call to sink? You would need to make at least two calls to divert all possible output. Check the documentation

Comment: related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124195/how-to-silence-the-output-from-system-commands-in-r

Answer (score 1):

Here's a crude but effective method. Just wrap your code inside this function:

```
in_silence <- function(...)
{
  mc <- match.call()[-1]
  a <- capture.output(
    tryCatch(
      suppressMessages(suppressWarnings(
      eval(as.list(mc)[[1]])
      )), error = function(e) ""))
}
```

So for example, if I do the following:

```
in_silence(
{
  write.csv(data.frame(a=1:3, b=1:3), "my.csv")
  print("hello")
  message("world")
  warning("Don't do it!")
  stop("I told you so!")
})
```

Nothing is written to the console from the print, message, warning or errors, but the csv is saved as expected. Of course, because your code is being executed inside a closure, you need to make sure that if you are assigning to variables you wish to access later you do so explicitly with `assign` or with `<<-`

Comment: Hi Allan, sorry for my late reply, lots of work todo. I'm very sorry to tell you, that your function does not solve my problem. I treid is letter by letter but the message still occurs. This seems to be no normal message and i don't even have a clue where it came from. It is written by the function: new('GDALReadOnlyDataset',filename)

Comment: @Christian can you try it after adding the parameter `type = "message"` to the `capture.output` call?

Comment: Tried it, no success, message still occurs. I guess that the class from the library rgdal is using something like system() in it??? but i am not sure. These messages looks like written with cat(), but whatever i do, they come up. But i have tried to suppress or catch these messages for weeks now, maybe this is the wrong way. Maybe you know how to turn of the consoleoutput in general? Or to redirect it like: Rscript file.r >> sillymessages.txt just within the rscript itself (sink can not redirect these messages)